# How to store authkey obtained from a JSON response to sqlite database in android?

Tags: android, json

How to store authkey obtained from a JSON response to sqlite database in android and validate before logging in?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to store in shared preferences as key value pair and validate user.
Visit this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Hope this helps.